# Cycling through all reports in Access

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have some code to build a basic report in access but, when I try to loop through all the reports with my variable rpt it skips the loop section, because nothing is assigned to the object. Any Ideas? What I need to get rpt to find the report with the caption qryDummy. Thanks in advance!   :-)

```
 Dim rptReport As Access.Report
 Dim strCaption As String
 Dim rpt As Report     
 CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryDummy").SQL = strSQL

     ' Open dummy query to invoke NewObjectAutoReport command on it
     ' Put the report created to design view to make properties editable

     With DoCmd
          .OpenQuery "qryDummy", acViewNormal
          .RunCommand acCmdNewObjectAutoReport
          .Close acQuery, "qryDummy"
          .RunCommand acCmdDesignView
      End With

      ' Get reference to just created report 

      ' !!!!!!!!!! This is the Section Giving me problems will !!!!!!!!!!!!!!  
      ' !!!!!!!!!! not loop through all the reports. !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

      For Each rpt In Reports
          If rpt.Caption = "qryDummy" Then Set rptReport = rpt
      Next

      With rptReport

          ' Create title control

          With CreateReportControl(.Name, acLabel, _
              acPageHeader, , ReportTitle, 0, 0)
              .FontBold = True
              .FontSize = 12
              .SizeToFit
          End With

          ' Create timestamp on footer

          CreateReportControl .Name, acLabel, _
              acPageFooter, , Now(), 0, 0

          ' Create page numbering on footer

          With CreateReportControl(.Name, acTextBox, _
              acPageFooter, , "='Page ' & [Page] & ' of ' & [Pages]", _
              .Width - 1000, 0)
              .SizeToFit
          End With

          ' Detach the report from dummy query

          .RecordSource = strSQL

          ' Set the report caption to autogenerated unique string

          strCaption = GetUniqueReportName
          If strCaption <> "" Then .Caption = strCaption

      End With

      DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPrintPreview

      Set rptReport = Nothing
```

### EDIT:

Ok So I guess my problem will use this snippet of code as the report is left open when the VBA runs:

```
For Each rpt In Reports
          If rpt.Caption = "qryDummy" Then Set rptReport = rpt
      Next
```

The only problem I have is it is not assigning rptReport = rpt I get the error: rpt = nothing, which results in rpt.caption = "Object variable or with block variable not set". So it is like the open report is not being seen?

FYI Solved the Problem need to change rpt.caption to rpt.Name Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vbs
Dim rpt As Report
For Each rpt In Reports
    Debug.Print rpt.Name
Next
```

will only iterate through Reports that are currently open. To iterate through *all* reports you need to do

```vbs
Dim rpt As Object
For Each rpt In Application.CurrentProject.AllReports
    Debug.Print rpt.Name
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help Gord, you have been a big help in my last few questions.